# C# \ Exchange 2010 PS1 Script

Tags: c#, .net, powershell-remoting, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to run a PS1 script using Exchange 2010 remote powershell and c#. I can connect and run the ps1 script but there are a few places in the script that use exchange cmdlets to update necessary user information. One cmdlet the script is using is update-recipient. The script runs fine until it trys to run this cmdlet and errors saying:

The term 'update-recipient' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Does anyone know if there are any restrictions on running cmdlets inside of PS1 scripts from c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run an Exchange 2010 powershell script from the command line, you need to load the Exchange components at the beginning of the powershell script. Add these 2 lines to your .ps1 file. Substitute your Exchange server's name for EXCHANGESERVER in the first line.

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://EXCHANGESERVER/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos

Import-PSSession $Session
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code ( in know it works for Exchange 2010)

```
        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(@"domain\user", createPassword("Pass"));
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, "exchange.ibm.com", 80, "/Powershell", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Default;
        Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

        try
        {
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

            Command objCommand = new Command("");
            objCommand.Parameters.Add("Identity", @"dom\user");
            pipeline.Commands.Add(objCommand);

            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        }
        catch 
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            runspace.Close();                   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this code for [Exchange 2007 from MSFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332449%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

```
       Runspace myRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        myRunspace.Open();

        RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
        PSSnapInInfo info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out snapInException);
        Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
        myRunSpace.Open(rsConfig);
```